# $\lim \limits_{x \to 0+} \frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist vs. $\lim \limits_{x \to 0+} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I can prove through contradiction (on the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition) that $\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist, but what exactly qualifies me to say that $\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$?

Comment: It isn't true. Did you mean $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac 1x = \infty \ ?$$

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Yes use $ \delta-\epsilon $ for one sided limits

Comment: Can you post the definition of limit that you are using?

Comment: You can say so if by $\infty$ you mean projective infinity rather than affine infinity.

Comment: You need to show that for any given $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that for every  $ 0 <x < \delta $. $ f(x) > \epsilon $ that's what the definition translates to in this case as far as I can tell correct me if I am mistaken

Comment: If you didn't not know about this variation you can visit khan academy to learn it. They have got great videos on this topic

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x) = \infty$ means $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}: \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in (a,a+\delta): f(x) > y$.

Compare this with the definition of a "proper limit":

$\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x) = L$ means $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+: \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in (a,a+\delta): |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Limits of functions are best defined by using the definition of sequential continuity, i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = b$ iff for all $a_n \rightarrow a$, you have $f(a_n) \rightarrow b$. So, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$ means that for any $(a_n)$ with $a_n \geq 0$ and $a_n \rightarrow 0$, you have $f(a_n) \rightarrow \infty$.